# How can the column name in'select column' be automatically updated after it has been edited?

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I am creating a R shiny app that accepts a csv file as input and depends upon the results I can use the buttons 'split columns' 'delete Rows' etc...

However, I added javascript(callback) for editing column names and called the 'callback' variable in the server function; it works fine, but when I edit column names, the select column' field is not updated automatically, however, when I do so for other functions like 'split column'  the 'select column' field is updated.

could someone help me to fix this issue?

**I've already added a server method for changing the column name.:**

```
  #Server functionf for editing the column names, javascript callback
  output[["table1"]] <- renderDT({
    
    datatable(rv$data, callback = JS(callback))
    
  }, server = FALSE)
```

**csv data**

```
ID  Type   Range
21  A1 B1   100
22  C1 D1   200
23  E1 F1   300
```

**app.R**
**EDITED**:

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(DT)
library(tibble)

#Javascript callback for editing the column names
callback <- c(
  "table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {",
  "  var $th = $(this);",
  "  var index = $th.index();",
  "  var colname = $th.text(), newcolname = colname;",
  "  var $input = $('<input type=\"text\">')",
  "  $input.val(colname);",
  "  $th.empty().append($input);",
  "  $input.on('blur', function(){",
  "    newcolname = $input.val();",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', {i: index, name: newcolname});",
  "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  });",
  "});"
)


###function for deleting the rows
splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}
###_______________________________________________
### function for inserting a new column

fillvalues <- function(data, values, columName){
  df_fill <- data
  vec <- strsplit(values, ",")[[1]]
  df_fill <- tibble::add_column(df_fill, newcolumn = vec, .after = columName)
  df_fill
}

##function for removing the colum

removecolumn <- function(df, nameofthecolumn){
  df[ , -which(names(df) %in% nameofthecolumn)]
}

### use a_splitme.csv for testing this program

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn", class = "btn-warning" ),
      uiOutput("selectUI"),
      
      
      actionButton("replacevalues", label = 'Replace values', class= "btn-Secondary"),
      actionButton("removecolumn", "Remove Column"),
      actionButton("Undo", 'Undo', style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows"),
      textInput("textbox", label="Input the value to replace:"),
      actionButton('downloadbtn', label= 'Download'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL, orig=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$orig <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
  
  output$selectUI<-renderUI({
    req(rv$data)
    selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', choices = names(rv$data))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    rv$data, server = F, editable = T
  )
  #includes extra column after the 'select column' and replaces the values specified 'Input the value to replace:'
  observeEvent(input$replacevalues, {
    rv$data <- fillvalues(rv$data, input$textbox, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  #Removing the specifield column through select column
  observeEvent(input$removecolumn, {
    rv$data <- removecolumn(rv$data,input$selectcolumn)
  })
  observeEvent(input$Undo, {
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
  #Storing the csv file through download button
  observeEvent(input$downloadbtn,{
    write.csv(rv$data,'test.csv')
    print ('file has been downloaded')
  })
  observeEvent(input$downloadbtn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Download Status.",
      paste0("csv file has been downloaded",input$downloadbtn,'.'),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
    
  })
  #Server functionf for editing the column names, javascript callback
  output[["table1"]] <- renderDT({
    
    datatable(rv$data, callback = JS(callback))
    
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  #datatable(rv$data,options = list(searching=FALSE, pageLength=100))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the index of the changed header and its name to Shiny in the `blur` listener with `Shiny.setInputValue`:

```
  "  }).on('blur', function(){",
  "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', {i: index+1, name: newcolname});",
  "  });",
```

In this way, in `server` you get `input[["newcol]]"`, a list with the index `i` and the new name `name`. Then observe this input and change the column names of `rv$data`:

```
observeEvent(input[["newcol"]], {
  i <- input[["newcol"]][["i"]]
  names(rv$data)[i] <- input[["newcol"]][["name"]]
})
```

## EDIT

In fact, the `change` listener is useless. You can use this callback:

```
callback <- c(
  "table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {",
  "  var $th = $(this);",
  "  var index = $th.index();",
  "  var colname = $th.text(), newcolname = colname;",
  "  var $input = $('<input type=\"text\">')",
  "  $input.val(colname);",
  "  $th.empty().append($input);",
  "  $input.on('blur', function(){",
  "    newcolname = $input.val();",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', {i: index, name: newcolname});",
  "    $(table.column(index).header()).text(newcolname);",
  "    $input.remove();",
  "  });",
  "});"
)
```

Comment: As I have tried I am getting the error `Error in c("table.on('dblclick.dt', 'thead th', function(e) {", "  var $th = $(this);",  : 
  argument 19 is empty`. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: @KevinTracey You likely forgot a comma, or you have an extra comma at the end of the callback.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, after removing the comma there is no error, but I am not able to edit the column names. It does  not allow me to edit the column names

Comment: @KevinTracey If it worked before it should still work with my single additional line. Did it work before?

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent, yes, it was working before.

Comment: looking for your help

Comment: @KevinTracey That should work. Double-check you have not done an error in the code.

Comment: I tried this code and on my side the blur listener did not appear to work. Inserting the `Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', {i: index, name: newcolname});` (with index value and not index+1) line after the `input$remove()` line in the *change* listener did the job. Not sure why the blur listener did not work though.

Comment: @julien.leroux5 Maybe  move this line before the `input$remove` line.

Comment: @julien.leroux5, @Stéphane Laurent,  Yes I have tried inserting the line `Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', {i: index, name: newcolname});`  before  the line `input$remove()` and after, both are not working. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: @KevinTracey Wait, why do you have an `$input.remove();` in the `change` listener? I am the author of this code, that you probably found on SO, and I don't see why there is an `$input.remove();` in the `change` listener. Try to remove it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I removed `$input.remove();`, still it does not work.

Comment: @KevinTracey i just edited my answer. Please try this new callback. It works for me.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I tried your new edited(callback) code as well, but it still doesn't work. Above,  I've included my updated code.

Comment: @KevinTracey Could you elaborate when you say it does not work? What does happen exactly? Do you get an error message ? Or what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236731/discussion-between-kevin-tracey-and-stephane-laurent).

Comment: I confirm the new callback works perfectly

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, 
There is no error message. The idea is that after renaming the column name, the new column will instantly fill in the list of 'Select Columns.' At the moment, it does not.

Comment: @julien.leroux5, did you check with my updated code?, are you able to replicate the column names (after edition) in 'Select Columns'?

Comment: Apparently you forgot the `observeEvent` part of @StéphaneLaurent's answer in your updated code

Comment: @KevinTracey Indeed you forgot the R part. The JavaScript function `Shiny.setInputValue('newcol', ......)` sends `input[["newcol"]]` to the R server, and you have to use this.